# Variable Width for Polymer Paper Tabs

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I want to implement the Polymer Paper Tabs, however I am struggling to find a way of having varying widths for the tabs.

I see that the scrollable tabs have the variable widths however I can not use these for my use case due to the scrolling arrows on display.

I have attempted to edit the CSS of the tabs by changing the widths manually however this changes all of the widths of the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `scrollable` attribute, it will make the widths of the tabs to be dynamic. You can also set the `hideScrollButton` attribute to prevent the arrows to be displayed.

`<paper-tabs selected="0" scrollable hide-scroll-button>`

Comment: Hi, I'm in the same boat here. `scrollable` does make the width to by dynamic, but `hideScrollButton` only makes the arrows opaque (instead of disappear). The arrows still show when many tabs are opened.

Comment: It should be dash cased that's why.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div wrapper above the paper tab and set the width

```
        <div id="tab_container" style="width:60%">
            <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}">
                <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
        </div>
```